# pointer to a structure within a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a structure (let's call it `structure1`) which holds a pointer to another structure (`structure2`), this way.

```
typedef struct structure{
    structure2 *pointer
}structure;

structure structVariable;
structVariable.pointer = functionThatReturnsAPointerToStructure2Variable();
```

The thing is, as the program changes context (for example, when calling functions), the return value of the following code changes

```
structVariable.pointer->someAttribute
```

Any idea of why this might be happening? If you need more info please ask. Thanks!

MORE INFO

This is the real-deal

structure would be this

```
typedef struct CPU{
    int variableCounter;
    int instructionPointer;
    char *currentInstruction;
    t_list *dataDictionary_list;
    u_int32_t currentContext;
    PCB *assignedPCB;
    CPU_STATUS status;
}CPU;
```

And this is how I assign the pointer (PCB *pointer)

```
PCB *pcb_createFromScript(const char *script){
    t_medatada_program *metadata = metadatada_desde_literal(script);
    PCB *pcb = malloc(sizeof(PCB));

pcb->instructionCount = metadata->instrucciones_size;
pcb->tagCount = metadata->cantidad_de_etiquetas;
pcb->functionCount = metadata->cantidad_de_funciones;

int codeSegmentSize = strlen(script);
int tagIndexSize = 0;

if(metadata->etiquetas != 0){
    tagIndexSize = strlen(metadata->etiquetas);
}

int instructionIndexSize = metadata->instrucciones_size * sizeof(t_intructions);

pcb_getSegments(pcb,1024,codeSegmentSize,tagIndexSize,instructionIndexSize);

pcb->currentContext = pcb->stackSegment;

pcb->variableCounter = 0;

memory_write(pcb->codeSegment,0,codeSegmentSize,script);
memory_write(pcb->tagIndexSegment,0,tagIndexSize,metadata->etiquetas);
memory_write(pcb->instructionIndexSegment,0,instructionIndexSize,(void *)metadata->instrucciones_serializado);

pcb->uniqueId = (int) random();
return pcb;
```

}

And then I assign it this way (myCPU is global), that's why I call it inside `cpu_getPCB` without passing it as a parameter

```
cpu_getPCB(*dummyPCB);

void cpu_getPCB(PCB myPCB){
    myCPU.currentContext = myPCB.currentContext;
    myCPU.assignedPCB = &myPCB;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing a complete test-case, we can only speculate.

Comment: Sounds like `functionThatReturnsAPointer...()` is returning a pointer to a local variable (which is no longer valid once the function returns).

Comment: Very likely the function that returns a pointer to structure2 is returning an address of a stack variable in the function. Other words, does your function that returns Structure2 return something that's created from malloc()?

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon yes, it does. It mallocs the structure inside the function, then returns it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some speculation.

If you are modifying the object that `structVariable.pointer` points to in some function, then when you try to read `structVariable.pointer->someAttribute`, that value will change to reflect to modification to the object.

Another possibility, as the other answer mentioned, is that `structVariable.pointer` is pointing to local memory (stack memory for a function) which can easily be overwritten on a new function call. That can be corrected by using `malloc` to do heap allocation instead of stack allocation.

---

Here is the first and most obvious issue. You are taking the address of a *parameter* and assigning it to `myCPU.assignedPCB`.

Since `C` is pass-by-value, you have copied it instead of capturing the original. Moreover, the parameter has the same lifetime as a local variable, and will go away when the function returns.

```
void cpu_getPCB(PCB myPCB){
    myCPU.currentContext = myPCB.currentContext;
    myCPU.assignedPCB = &myPCB;
}
```

You can fix it by passing a pointer instead, since you are in `C` and do not have access to the reference type.

```
void cpu_getPCB(PCB* myPCB){
    myCPU.currentContext = myPCB->currentContext;
    myCPU.assignedPCB = myPCB;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think the second possibility might be the case here, since the attributes change randomly, I am not actually changing any of them, and the values they get are completely random. I will edit my post to add how I am creating the pointer.

Comment: @GuillermoGruschka, Sounds good. If you show the function that creates the pointer, I can show you how to correct it, usually with a one-line change.

Answer (score 1):

The "structure2 *pointer" will be pointing at a piece of memory that will disappear when you change context. Allocate the Structure2 variable and free it when it's no longer needed

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: I imagined it would be a problem of that kind, I added some code, could you give me your opinion?